# Can radiant pokemon count as rule box?

Tags: pokemon

Is it true that [Radiant Pokémon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Radiant_Pok%C3%A9mon_(TCG)) are counted as "rule box Pokémon"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radiant Pokémon are rule box pokemon, because they have a rule box that reads "Radiant Pokémon Rule".  For example, [Radiant Greninja](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/ss-series/swsh10/46/):

[image: Image of Radiant Greninja card]

You can see the "Radiant Pokémon Rule" just below the picture of the Pokémon.

This is further clarified in the [Pokémon TCG Rulebook](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/rules) in appendix 5:

> All Radiant Pokémon appear with their special Shiny coloration and have the Radiant Pokémon Rule, which says you can’t have more than 1 Radiant Pokémon in your deck. **A Radiant Pokémon is considered a Pokémon with a Rule Box.** Note that “Radiant” is part of the Pokémon’s name, so your deck could include 4 Greninja and 1 Radiant Greninja. Radiant Pokémon are always Basic Pokémon and do not evolve from or into any other card.

(Bolding added)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some of the Radiant Pokémon are Rule Box Pokémon.

Rule Box refers to any Pokémon that has a text box that says the word “rule,” such as “V rule” or “TAG TEAM rule.”  If your radiant Pokémon has that, it is rule Box one.

Here is [the list of Pokémon that are considered to have a Rule Box](https://www.pokemon.com/us/sword-shield-chilling-reign-banned-list-and-rule-changes-announcement/#:%7E:text=A%20Pok%C3%A9mon%20with%20a%20Rule,that%20don%27t%20exist%20currently.):

- Pokémon V
- Pokémon VMAX
- Pokémon-GX
- Prism Star Pokémon
- TAG TEAM Pokémon
- Pokémon-EX
- Mega Evolution Pokémon
- Pokémon BREAK

Comment: Ugh, this is a chatGPT answer.  Very close to correct, but very chatGPT.

Comment: @Joe i can assure you, no chatGPT was involved in the process of answering it.

Comment: That's ... very disappointing, then.  It's inaccurate, in any event; Radiant Pokemon are a particular kind of card, and all of them are rule box pokemon (they're sort of similar to Prism Star pokemon).  I'll be honest, though, I don't believe you: posting a link to a 2021 article (in chatGPT's timeframe) and failing to understand from context that Radiant Pokemon are a specific thing (which again from 2021 before they existed, ChatGPT wouldn't) seems very much like it's LLM... and if not you just googled "rule box pokemon" and pasted the first link from google, which isn't much better.

Comment: Please see the edit that was made to the post itself. The original answer was just the first two paragraphs

Comment: That doesn't make your answer any more correct or any less just "google and paste first response without understanding it", though... it's still largely incorrect and outdated.